# Spring Boot - Enable SSL (HTTPS) with CA certificate

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, https, jks

Maybe I will find help here. I want to enable SSL on Spring Boot application. I have a configuration like:

> server:   port: 8999   ssl:
>       enabled: true
>       key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
>       key-store-password: mypass
>       key-password: mypass

The problem is my keystore. I've imported *crt file into keystore with alias 'tomcat':

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.crt -keystore native.jks -alias tomcat
```

However, I still can't properly access my rest api. It vomits with error in firefox:

> SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

- it doesn't work. How can I make proper keystore to make it work? I'm issuing with CA certificate, NOT self-signed. I have files like:

> certificate.crt, certificate.p12, certificate.pk, privkey.pem and
>   three files root_ca_1.ca-bundle, root_ca_2.ca-bundle,
>   root_ca_3.ca-bundle

. That's all I have. I'm very fresh with ssl topic, just read some tutorials and tried few keytool commands to make it work. I'd be grateful for help. Thank You in advance.

Comment: maybe this helps https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Thank You for reply. However, this tutorial doesn't resolve my problem since it's based on self-signed certificate. I'm desperately searching for clues how can I import CA certificate properly to my keystore.

Answer (score 13):

I just spent the afternoon figuring out this exact problem, so I'll share my process here.

Each of the references below provides instructions on how to generate and use a self-signed certificate. That's not exactly what I'm trying to do, but these each contain some useful background information.

REFERENCES:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate
- https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ssl-https-examples/
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-enable-the-https-into-spring-boot-applicati

I have already purchased a real CA-issued SSL certificate for the *.jimtough.org 'wildcard' domain. I purchased the certificate from http://www.namecheap.com/, but the actual Certificate Authority (CA) is Comodo.

As part of the purchase/activation procedure with the CA, I needed to follow these instructions:

- https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9592/14/generating-a-csr-on-amazon-web-services-aws/

Note that I opted to follow their AWS instructions because I am an AWS user and have an EC2 server readily available with OpenSSL and Java already installed on the server. There are lots of other alternatives to do the same procedure, so search further to find the 'generating a CSR' instructions that are right for you.

At the end of this step, I have the following two files:

- `csr.pem` - This is used as part of the SSL cert request/activation process
- `private.key` - This is the private key part of my SSL cert, which I will need later to install the cert on my servers. **Keep it secret. Keep it safe.**

After I completed the purchase and verification procedure for my SSL cert, the CA sent me back a .zip file that contained a .p7b, .crt, and .ca-bundle file.

One of the reference links below explains the difference between these certificate file types:

- `.p7b` - This type should be compatible with Java-based applications (PKCS#7 format)
- `.crt` - This type should be compatible with most everything else - the link above suggests this is PEM format
- `.ca-bundle` - Not sure when to use this - the link above suggests this is PEM format

REFERENCES:

- https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/what-are-certificate-formats-and-what-is-the-difference-between-them/

Next I need to figure out how to use the files that I listed above to configure my Spring Boot application for HTTPS.

I will follow the relevant parts of the below tutorials to get what I need:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate
- https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

*NOTE: In both tutorials, I will NOT follow their sections on creating a self-signed certificates, since I already possess a real certificate that was issued by a real CA.*

The first relevant step in their instructions is to create a new Java keystore. The requirements are:

- Must have Java installed, so I have access to the 'keytool' utility
- Must have the 'openssl' utility installed, so I can create a .p12 file using my .key and .p7b files as input

I will use my AWS EC2 Linux server to do this. My server already has the Java/keytool and OpenSSL utilities installed.
First I need to use the OpenSSL utility to create a .p12 file that (if I understand correctly) will contain both my
private key, and the CA-issue certificate. Second, I need to create a new Java keystore that will contain an imported
copy of the .p12 file.

- `openssl pkcs12 -export -out jimtough-dot-org.p12 -name "jimtough-dot-org" -inkey private.key -in __jimtough_org.crt`

  - IMPORTANT: You need to provide a password at the 'export password' prompt, otherwise the keytool import in the next step will fail
- `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jimtough-dot-org.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore jimtough-dot-org-keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS`

  - You will need to provide the password you used in the 'openssl' command
  - You will also need to provide a new password for the keystore that you are creating
- (OPTIONAL) `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jimtough-dot-org-keystore.jks -destkeystore jimtough-dot-org-keystore.pkcs12 -deststoretype pkcs12`

  - I received a warning from 'keytool' about JKS being a proprietary format, and a suggestion that I convert my keystore to PKCS12 format, so I did so with this optional command

---

Finally, I need to package my newly created Java keystore with my Spring Boot application and configure the application to use it.

REFERENCES:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate
- https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

I referred back to the two Baeldung tutorials above, and was able to get the details I needed to make my Spring Boot (with Spring Security enabled) to work.

I created a new 'keystore' folder under the existing 'src/main/resources', and copied both of my newly created keystore files there (I kept both formats).

I added the block below to my Spring Boot application's `application.properties` file.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SSL CONFIGURATION
# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
#server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
#server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/jimtough-dot-org-keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/jimtough-dot-org-keystore.pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=mykeystorepassword
server.ssl.key-alias=jimtough-dot-org
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.port=8443
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As expected, I get a bunch of warnings from my browser when I attempt to connect to a locally running instance of the Spring Boot application using https://localhost:8443/ as the URL. This happens because the browser correctly identifies the mismatch between 'localhost' and the expected 'jimtough.org' domain that my SSL certificate was created to run on. There shouldn't be any warnings when I deploy the application to a server whose hostname is 'anything.jimtough.org' (or just [www.jimtough.org](http://www.jimtough.org)).

**That's it! Happy HTTPS'ing!**

Comment: This was excellent and everything I needed because I already had a purchased certificate. Everything thing else I found was for self-signed certificates which wasn't realistic for production. Just wanted to add that these are the steps I ultimately followed and skipped the initial ones: 1) I already had a .pfx file from my ssl provider, so I downloaded the private key and the .pfx file 2) I learned that a .pfx file is also a .p12 file and you can rename if you want to. I didn't do this and just used the .pfx file and generated my keystore. 3) I then used the keystore to generate pkcs12 file

Comment: You saved my day ! thanks nice step by step explanation. I was using steps for installing Godday ssl for frontend and backened both. It works like charm

Comment: How do I enable HTTPS only if the key-store file exists? If it's not found, I want to use HTTP.

Comment: Hello @JimTough I have followed your instructions cause I have tried nearly everything but I still have in browser net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID even thought I am sure that my settings in application.properties and data in keystore are correct. I am running webflux java application from jar on linux vps server and I user cerbot to get certificate and private key or both in chain. So question is, why my webflux is refusing calls from hosting with reason io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use spring-boot for SSL-connections. Let a reverse proxy handle the SSL-termination.
So it is possible, that a tool can automatic renew your certificates (like the certbot).
And you don't need to put a (sercret) private-key to your application.

It is simpler to share your application. A server-admin needs only to setup reverse proxy (or have something familar already in cloud-systems like kubernetes) and can scale up your application.

#### Benefits

- Scalable application
- Simpler spring-setup
- No secrets in your application
- Simpler use of application (#cloudSystems)
- Most reverseProxies are compatible with certbot

Comment: Despite the downvote, this is actually a good recommendation. While it doesn't answer the question, sometimes it is good to look outside the question. If one uses a reverse proxy, it gets one out completely of the business of creating keystores and adding certs, etc. And it is very likely one will run into a certbot issued cert, which means the cert needs renewed frequently. That all fits very nicely in an apache/nginx based reverse proxy, and can be automated easily and supported easily. And when an app scales to need load balancing and content acceleration, you end up behind a RP anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you require few more properties to be added in ssl configuration

```
server:
ssl:
  key-store: classpath:config/tls/keystore.p12
  key-store-password: password ##this will be your certificate password
  key-store-type: PKCS12
  ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
  enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
http2:
  enabled: true
```

Make sure that the p12 keystore file is present  under classpath (src/main/resources)  in config/tls

> But to generate keystore file use the below openssl command where you
>   will use .crt and .key file to generate .p12 file.
>
> .crt and .key are present under Folder CA and file p12 file will be
>   generated  under CA
>
> Please note that you will asked for the certificate password after
>   running the below command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in CA/certificate.crt -inkey CA/certificate.key -name certificate -out CA/certificate.p12
```

> If you want to add this certificate to your local cacert then use the
>   below command
>
> under jre\lib\security

```
keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts  -alias ca.certificate  -file   CA/certificate.crt -keystore   cacerts -storepass changeit
```